# Firebase Cloud Functions - Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am writing functions typescript and here is my code:

```
const followerColl = 
admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(updatersUserId).collection('followers')

return followerColl.get().then((querySnapshot: { documents: DocumentSnapshot[] }) => {
//This line below seems to be the one causing the error
const promises = querySnapshot.documents.map((doc) => {
    const followerUid = doc.id
    return admin.firestore().collection('Users').doc(followerUid).collection('followers')
    .doc(updatersUserId).set({
        name: newName, 
        userName: newUserName,
        profilePhotoChosen: profilePhotoChosen,
        uid: updatersUserId
    })
})
return Promise.all(promises)
})
```

So I am querying all the documents in a collection named 'followers' then mapping the querysnapshot.documents into a doc. The mapping part is where the error occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) does not have a `documents` property but has a [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) one.

So you should do:

```
querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {...});
```